# Unload CSV File when Form is closed

Tags: vb.net, csv, import

In my app I have a form that import to mysql from a csv file.
but when I close it the csv file is still in use by my app.

here the Code of CSV import:

```vb
    Private Sub Btn_brow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_brow.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Try
            With ofd
                .Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"
                .FilterIndex = 1
                .Title = "Import data from CSV File"
            End With
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                txtLocation.Text = ofd.FileName

                Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName)

                Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(";"c)
                dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), New DataColumn(newline(1)), New DataColumn(newline(2)), New DataColumn(newline(3))})
                While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
                    newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(";"c)
                    Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                    newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1), newline(2), newline(3)}
                    dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
                End While
                Dgv_Import.DataSource = dt


            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see anything that touches a CSV file.

Comment: This scares me. It looks a bit like the `saveData()` method and SQL string do not use parameterized queries, but rather only use string concatenation to build the INSERT statements. That's gonna be _crazy vulnerable_ to injection issues.

Comment: sry, I added the file upload code

Comment: You're not closing the StreamReader. Put that code into a using block and it'll close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing the line `Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName)` with `Using sr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName)`? Then add `End Using` after the `End While`.

This will automatically dispose of the StreamReader object when it's done with it.